# Strange gain change after initializing kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO

Tags: objective-c, audio, core-audio

I'm writing app that records sound with `kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO` audio unit. And there is strange bug I'm trying to catch for a couple days. Internal microphone gain is changed automatically for whole system after I create new instance of VPIO unit.

Initialization code:

```
AudioComponentDescription audioComponentDescriptionWildcard =
  {
    kAudioUnitType_Output,
    kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO,
    kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple
   };

AudioComponent audioComponent = 
  AudioComponentFindNext(NULL,   
  &audioComponentDescriptionWildcard);


OSStatus status = AudioComponentInstanceNew(audioComponent, &audioComponentInstance);
```

Simplest way to verify the problem is to make a breakpoint on `AudioComponentInstanceNew` call and start skype call to skype test call service. Before this line executes recorded voice is loud and clear. After executing this line microphone level drops dramatically.

With other units everything is normal. And app doesn't interfere with other recording applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because automatic gain control is enabled by default. You'll need to change the kAUVoiceIOProperty_VoiceProcessingEnableAGC property to 0.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AudioUnitPropertiesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Voice_Processing_I_O_Audio_Unit_Properties

Comment: We see this too, but setting this property doesn't help. We're on the Mac. Not sure if OP was on Mac or iOS.